# Create table with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

I'm working on PostgreSQL 9.1, and I have the following tables:

```
element(element_id int, name varchar, category_id int)

category(category_id int, name varchar)

characteristic(characteristic_id int, name varchar, unit varchar)

category_characteristic(characteristic_id, category_id)

element_characteristic(element_id, characteristic_id, value)
```

Imagine the following tables:

```
elements
 ---------------------
|id|name    |category |
-----------------------
|1 |'item 1'|1        |
|2 |'item 2'|2        |
|3 |'item 3'|1        |
 ---------------------

category
 ----------------
|id|name         |
|----------------|
|1 | 'category 1'|
|2 | 'category 2'|
 ----------------

characteristic
 --------------------------------
|id|name               |unit     |
 --------------------------------
|1 |'characteristic 1' | 'unit 1'| 
|2 |'characteristic 2' | 'unit 2'|
|3 |'characteristic 3' | 'unit 3'|
|4 |'characteristic 4' | 'unit 4'|
|5 |'characteristic 5' | 'unit 5'|
|6 |'characteristic 6' | 'unit 6'|
 --------------------------------

category_characteristic
 ------------------------------
|category_id|characteristic_id |
|------------------------------
|1          |1                 |
|1          |2                 |   
|1          |4                 |
|1          |5                 |
|2          |1                 |
|2          |3                 |
|2          |5                 |
 ------------------------------

element_characteristic
 ---------------------------------------
|id_element|id_characteristic|value     |
|---------------------------------------|
|1         |1                |'value a' |
|1         |2                |'value b' |
|1         |4                |'value c' |
|1         |5                |'value d' |
|2         |1                |'value e' |
|2         |3                |'value f' |
|2         |5                |'value g' |
|3         |1                |'value h' |
|3         |2                |'value i' |
|3         |4                |'value j' |
|3         |5                |'value k' |
 ---------------------------------------
```

And now I want to get the following tables:

```
 category 1
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name   |characteristic 1|characteristic 2|characteristic 4|characteristic 5|
| --------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|item 1 |value a         |value b         |value c         |value d         |
|item 3 |value h         |value i         |value j         |value k         |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

category 2
 -----------------------------------------------------------
|name   |characteristic 1|characteristic 3|characteristic 5|
| ----------------------------------------------------------
|item 2 |value e         |value f         |value g         |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to understand what is the best procedure to go trough. I've read the tablefunc documentation but I just can't figure out how to make that procedures dynamically because there will be N entries on the category table. Some kind of directions will be very appreciated.

Comment: +1 Nicely formatted, complete question.

Comment: Be warned: This is an "Entity Attribute Value" model. These can be powerful toys at the beginning and a _very_ bad performance hog at the end. Lookup Google for "reviews". You might also lookup hstore for a PostgreSQL specific but more performant solution.

Comment: In my case I think this is the right way to go. I'm managing from 100 to 1000 elements, performance doesn't seem to be the problem for this type of numbers... And besides that, I really need this type of structure because I'll need it later to perform calculations. Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab (
        'SELECT e.name, c.name, ec.value
         FROM   elements e
         JOIN   element_characteristic ec ON ec.id_element = e.id
         JOIN   characteristic c ON c.id = ec.id_characteristic
         ORDER  BY 1, 2',

        'SELECT DISTINCT name
         FROM   characteristic
         ORDER  BY 1')
AS tbl (
  name text
 ,characteristic_1 text
 ,characteristic_2 text
 ,characteristic_3 text
 ,characteristic_4 text
 ,characteristic_5 text
 ,characteristic_6 text
 );
```

Test setup:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE elements(id int, name text, category int);
INSERT INTO elements VALUES
 (1, 'item 1', 1)
,(2, 'item 2', 2)
,(3, 'item 3', 1);

CREATE TEMP TABLE element_characteristic(id_element int
                                        ,id_characteristic int, value text);
INSERT INTO element_characteristic VALUES
 (1,1,'value a')
,(1,2,'value b')
,(1,4,'value c')
,(1,5,'value d')
,(2,1,'value e')
,(2,3,'value f')
,(2,5,'value g')
,(3,1,'value h')
,(3,2,'value i')
,(3,4,'value j')
,(3,5,'value k');

CREATE TEMP TABLE characteristic (id int, name text, unit text);
INSERT INTO characteristic VALUES
 (1,'characteristic 1', 'unit 1')
,(2,'characteristic 2', 'unit 2')
,(3,'characteristic 3', 'unit 3')
,(4,'characteristic 4', 'unit 4')
,(5,'characteristic 5', 'unit 5')
,(6,'characteristic 6', 'unit 6');
```

Result:

```
  name | characteristic 1 | characteristic_2 | characteristic_3 | characteristic_4 | characteristic_5 | characteristic_6
-------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|----------------
item 1 | value a          | value b          | <NULL>           | value c          | value d          | <NULL>
item 2 | value e          | <NULL>           | value f          | <NULL>           | value g          | <NULL>
item 3 | value h          | value i          | <NULL>           | value j          | value k          | <NULL>
```

The solution for your problem is to use the `crosstab()` variant with **two parameters**.

The query outputs *all items*. Add a `WHERE` clause to the first query to filter for category.

The second parameter (another query string) produces the list of output columns, so that `NULL` values in the data query (the first parameter) are assigned correctly.

Check the manual for the [tablefunc extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html), and in particular `crosstab(text, text)`:

I have posted a couple of answer concerning `crosstab()` functions of the tablefunc module. [This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:939860%20%2bcrosstab&submit=search) will give you more examples and explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked out great! Just one question, this example I only have 6 characteristics, what if I have an unknown number of characteristics(let's say 100 characteristics, in a mean of 4~7 characteristic per category)? Creating a procedure to complete the query with the number of characteristics is the right way to go? Once again, thank you very much, I'll read your functab related articles.

Comment: @NewK: Glad it works! As for the case with 100+ characteristics, this is a different question. I suggest you **open a new one** where you define what you want back exactly. All 100 characteristic in separate rows? 10 rows with column names in the data? Sorted by number of characteristics? You can always reference this question if you don't want to repost the same data model.